# NERDTree (Vim): How to open a file with path in NERDTree quickly

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm newbie in vim (NERDTree). 
My question:
  How to open a file with a path by command (like: vim /etc/hosts)
  And open this file in new tab

Thanks for help.

Comment: FYI: NerdTree is not the only way to open a file in Vim. See `:h :e`, `:h wildcards`, `:h cmdline-completion`. You may also want to turn on `'wildmenu` via `set wildmenu`.

Comment: I also recommend [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) plugin, with it's fuzzy search you can find the file you want to open really quickly, and then send it easily to current window, new split or new tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just type in:

```
:tabnew /path/to/file
```

If you want to use NERDTree, you can open `NERDTree` (type `:NERDTree`), navigate to your file, and then press <kbd>t</kbd> with cursor on the file name. This will open specific file in new tab.

Also, while in `NERDTree`, you can hit <kbd>?</kbd>. That will show you it's internal help with list of available commands. Hit <kbd>?</kbd> again to exit help and enjoy :)

See also `:help NERDTree`, if you want more complete documentation.

Answer (score 3):

`:tabnew` some/path/to/some/file